# What is the correct and most safe way to check if HTML form checkboxes and such have been POST-set?

Tags: html, php

This has confused me since the early days. Maybe it's just in my head, but it seems to me as if this has varied over time, between browsers, and possibly even depending on the local language/locale.

Basically, whenever I need to check if a HTML input of type "radio" or "checkbox" has been set, I always do:

```
if (isset($_POST['the_name']) && trim($_POST['the_name']))
    // do stuff
```

This just makes sure that the POST variable is sent whatsoever (which in itself doesn't mean that it was actually checked/selected, as far as I can tell, since its "value" can be an empty string) and that it's something other than '' (empty string). It *seems* like this has worked for a long time, but I have two problems with it:

1. It's ugly. I need to abstract it into a function, but then I want to know if it's a good idea in the first place, or wrong somehow.
2. It makes the assumption that *any* non-empty string value means "checked" or "selected", whereas the standard may say a specific string value such as "on", or maybe any number of such strings depending on the language/locale.

Are there cases where my above code falls apart? Do browsers ever submit POST forms where they include names which have no user input/selection in the HTTP request? Or does the existence of a name in the POST blob mean that that "field" has been actively changed/set/checked/selected?

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind checkboxes is that the value is sent over to the server only if the checkbox was checked when submitting the form. The value can be anything, even an empty string. As long as the field is part of the transmitted form it means the box was ticked.

> The `value` attribute is one which all `<input>`s share; however, it serves a special purpose for inputs of type `checkbox`: when a form is submitted, only checkboxes which are currently checked are submitted to the server, and the reported value is the value of the `value` attribute. If the `value` is not otherwise specified, it is the string `on` by default.

This means you could have a form like this:

```
<form action="" method="get">
<input type="checkbox" name="c1" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

If the checkbox is **not** checked when submitting then `$_GET` will be an empty array.
If the checkbox is checked then the value of `$_GET` will be:

```
array('c1' => '');
```

To check whether the box was ticked when sending the form you **only** need `isset()`

```
if (isset($_POST['c1']) {
    // The box was checked!
}
```

Sometimes you would like to assign a `value` attribute to your checkbox. In such situations you can use the shorthand operator for `isset()` function `??`.

```
// Create a variable from the checkbox value or assign an empty string if the box was not checked
$nyCheckbox = $_POST['c1'] ?? '';
```